# Getting Memory Error in PySpark during Filter & GroupBy computation

Tags: dataframe, filter, group-by, pyspark, out-of-memory

This is the Error :
**Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 37.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 37.0 (TID 325, 10.139.64.5, executor 20): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 20 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages***

So is there any alternative, more efficient way to apply those function without causing out-of-memory error? I have the data in Billions to be computed.

```
Input Dataframe on which filtering is to be done: 
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|Pos_id|level_p|skill_p|Emp_id|level_e|skill_e|
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|     1|      2|      a|   100|      2|      a|
|     1|      2|      a|   100|      3|      f|
|     1|      2|      a|   100|      2|      d|
|     1|      2|      a|   101|      4|      a|
|     1|      2|      a|   101|      5|      b|
|     1|      2|      a|   101|      1|      e|
|     1|      2|      a|   102|      5|      b|
|     1|      2|      a|   102|      3|      d|
|     1|      2|      a|   102|      2|      c|
|     2|      2|      d|   100|      2|      a|
|     2|      2|      d|   100|      3|      f|
|     2|      2|      d|   100|      2|      d|
|     2|      2|      d|   101|      4|      a|
|     2|      2|      d|   101|      5|      b|
|     2|      2|      d|   101|      1|      e|
|     2|      2|      d|   102|      5|      b|
|     2|      2|      d|   102|      3|      d|
|     2|      2|      d|   102|      2|      c|
|     2|      4|      b|   100|      2|      a|
|     2|      4|      b|   100|      3|      f|
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Filtering Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
function = udf(lambda item, items: 1 if item in items else 0, IntegerType())
df_result = new_df.withColumn('result', function(sf.col('skill_p'), sf.col('skill_e')))

df_filter = df_result.filter(sf.col("result") == 1)
df_filter.show()

res = df_filter.groupBy("Pos_id", "Emp_id").agg(
      sf.collect_set("skill_p").alias("SkillsMatch"),
      sf.sum("result").alias("SkillsMatchedCount"))
res.show()
```

This needs to be done on Billions of rows.

Comment: You need to set options for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and `spark.default.parallelism`.